# Verbs that do not have some conjugation forms

Tags: verbs

In Russian there is a verb "*победить*" (*vincere*) which doesn't have  future singular 1st person form.  It is impossible to say "*io vincerò (in questo gioco, in questa partita)*" in Russian using this verb.

Are there any verbs in Italian which do not have some grammatical form?

Comment: Yes, they are called "difettivi" (i.e. defective). See http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-difettivi_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/. Examples are *urgere* and *secernere*. I'll write an answer later, if no one beats me :).

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!!

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking. If your nickname were to mean “(male) Russian tourist” in Italian, it should be *turista russo*.

Comment: Here is a website giving the full table of tenses for several hundred Italian verbs.
https://www.italian-verbs.com/italyanskiye-glagoly/konyugatsiya.php

Comment: @DaG I assumed it was intentional...

Comment: @DaG Yes, thank you! It's a quotation from a well-known Soviet comedy :) _(see link in my profile)_

Comment: @DaG: It's explained here: https://books.google.es/books?id=AjcuDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22The+Diamond+Arm%22+russo+turisto&source=bl&ots=oSWTSavIae&sig=-6ZotW7c5Gxk7731pyC5fCSULhM&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-tdivi7LYAhXM7BQKHSoIA_oQ6AEIITAI#v=onepage&q=%22The%20Diamond%20Arm%22%20russo%20turisto&f=false.

Comment: Oh, I see! Sorry for hinting it were wrong Italian. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some verbs, such as *competere*, *concernere*, *dirimere*, *divergere*, *esimere*, *incombere*, *inerire*, *soccombere*, *splendere*, *suggere*, and *transigere* don’t have a past participle. [(source)](http://archive.is/MKufN#selection-1981.0-2053.2)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: The linked resource is blocked in Russia where I am now. I'll have to wait until I'm in Europe again.

Comment: @RussoTuristo: It's a copy of this: http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_219.html.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that *solere* does not have future, conditional and imperative tenses (as they'd sound weird or nonsensical, e.g. *io sorrò, lui sorrebbe*).

A common category of impersonal verbs (to rain *piovere*, to hail *grandinare*) don't conjugate except for 3rd-person. This rule also applies to Italian.

Some older uses of certain verbs are also defective, e.g. *ire* (use *andare* instead), *molcere* (use *addolcire*) and *calere* (use *importare*).

Comment: Well, it was not that way in Dante Alighieri's texts. For instance, in Canto XXIV of *Inferno*, Vanni Fucci says «Io piovvi di Toscana».

Comment: *Piovere* è sicuramente coniugato anche alla prima e seconda persona, anche se raro: ad esempio [qui](https://books.google.fr/books?id=r4hnp6piaYAC&pg=PA87&dq=%22piover%C3%B2%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6kN_zx_reAhUSUBoKHX89AxEQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22piover%C3%B2%22&f=false) e [qui](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6K0Gd2uPNo4C&pg=PA143&dq=%22piovesti%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio7ue6yPreAhVBPBoKHRP7CSsQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22piovesti%22&f=false)

Comment: @DenisNardin Sì e lo so. Ma come *piovo* e *piovi* non sono utilizzati al giorno d'oggi (anche se furono), penso che *piovere* è difettivo.

Answer (score 1):

You should always look up the verb in a good Italian dictionary or a verb reference like those, in order to find out missing or obsolete verb forms:

- Fabrizio Berloco's [*The Big Book of Italian Verbs: 900 Fully Conjugated Verbs in all Tenses. With IPA Transcription (2018)*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DYynDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- Katrien Maes-Christie's *The Big Green Book of Italian Verbs (2004)*

Other good online resources are [verbix.com](https://www.verbix.com) and [italian-verbs.com](https://www.italian-verbs.com); they are free but sometimes you'll probably find some mistakes in some verb forms.

Comment: It's a good approach to find different verb forms, but its not very good for finding verbs which lack some particular forms.